# Explain the terms k-simplex and simplical complex geometrically?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I m new to algebraic topology .so confused with these terms
pls suggest simple books

Comment: I liked "Elements of Algebraic Topology" by James Munkres ... So, I would recommend having a look at that. The book literally begins with the definition of "simplicial complex" and has plenty of exercises and examples to illustrate the various definitions and theorems.

Comment: Thanku so much http://math.stackexchange.com/users/10467/amitesh-datta .that book is very useful

Comment: Thanks, @Sree. That's great! It is certainly an excellent textbook, in my opinion, and you will learn a lot of fun algebraic topology if you read it cover to cover.